# Neo4j Trigger Example Using TransactionEventHandler()

Tags: java, neo4j, triggers, cypher

I would like to build out a set of triggers in my database using [TransactionEventHandler()](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/event/TransactionEventHandler.html) functionality.

However I haven't found a working example of this for version > 3.0. I did see an example by [maxdemarzi](https://github.com/maxdemarzi/neo_listens) however it doesn't appear to be working in recent versions of neo4j.

If anyone has any experience with this I would really appreciate the help!

Side Note: I do realize APOC has some alpha functinality around triggers using cypher. At the moment it isn't fully fledged and I have run into some issues using it. Thus I'm looking at implementing my own plugin to handle my particular use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reaching out to maxdemarzi on github he has updated his example to support neo4j v 3.1.

See the repo here: https://github.com/maxdemarzi/neo_listens